# Looking for an OSX application that can do image processing using a webcam

Tags: macos, image-processing, scripting, webcam, object-detection

I'm looking for an OSX (or Linux?) application that can recieve data from a webcam/video-input and let you do some image processing on the pixels in something similar to c or python or perl, not that bothered about the processing language.

I was considering throwing one together but figured I'd try and find one that exists already first before I start re-inventing the wheel.

Wanting to do some experiments with object detection and reading of dials and numbers.

Comment: Managed to set the camera up facing my analogue gas meter (natural gas) and detect where the red dial is facing; Tracking the dial I can work out my KWH-usage of gas and start gathering and graphing the data to get an idea of how inefficient my boiler is!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to do a little coding, you want to take a look at QTKit, the QuickTime framework for Cocoa. QTKit will let you easity set up an input source from the webcam (intro [here](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/qtkit.html)). You can also apply Core Image filters to the stream (demo code [here](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/MyMovieFilter/index.html)). If you want to use OpenGL to render or apply filters to the movie, check out Core Video (examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/QuickTime/idxCocoa-date.html)).

Using the[MyMovieFilter](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/MyMovieFilter/index.html) demo should get you up and running very quickly.

Comment: I'm a full time software developer so coding is second nature - I originally planned to start the project straight in Cocoa but decided that prototyping first would be the best solution until I can nail down all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Found a cross platform tool called 'Processing', actually ran the windows version to avoid further complications getting the webcams to work.

Had to install quick time, and something called gVid to get it to work but after the initial hurdle coding seems like C; (I think it gets "compiled" into Java), and it runs quite fast; even scanning pixels from the webcam in real time.

Still to get it working on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what processing you want to do (i.e. if it's a filter that's available in Apple's Core Image filter library), the built-in [Photo Booth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_Booth) app may be all you need. There's a comercial set of add-on filters  available from the Apple store as well ([http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/imaging_3d/composerfxeffectsforphotobooth.html)](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/imaging_3d/composerfxeffectsforphotobooth.html).